How to remove item from observable list?
I have a simple todo list that when clicking on "complete", it should remove that item from the list, but nothing seems to be happenning when clicking on it.
Stackblitz: Link
HTML:
<div *ngIf="list$; else noList">
  <div *ngFor="let data of list$ | async" class="items">
    <div>{{ data.id }} -</div>
    <div>{{ data.description }}</div>
    <button (click)="complete(data)">Complete</button>
  </div>
</div>
<button (click)="add()">Add</button>

<ng-template #noList>
  <h1>Loading...</h1>
</ng-template>

service:
complete(data: any) {
    console.log(data.id);

    let result = this.data$
      .pipe(
        filter((x: any) => x.id !== data.id),
        tap((x: any) => console.log(x))
      )
      .subscribe((val: any) => {
        this.resultObs = of(val);
        console.log(val);
        console.log(this.resultObs);
      });

    return this.resultObs;
  }


The filter pipe operator does not itself filter arrays. It filters data going through the pipe. If you have this:
arr$: Observable<any[]> = of([1, 2]);

arr$.pipe(
    filter((x) => . . .)
)

x in the filter function will be the entire [1, 2] array, not each element of the array. filter here filters the entirety of data coming through the pipe. You could use it, for example, to prevent the subscribe callback from running unless the user had more than 4 todos:
arr$: Observable<any[]> = of([1, 2]);

arr$.pipe(
    filter((todos: any[]) => todos.length > 4)
).subscribe(() => {
    console.log("Will not run")
});

arr$.pipe(
    filter((todos: any[]) => todos.length < 4)
).subscribe(() => {
    console.log("Will run, since the length of the array is less than 4")
});

If you want to transform the object going through the pipe, you'd use map:
let result = this.data$
  .pipe(
    map((xs: any[]) => xs.filter((x) => x.id !== data.id)),
    tap((xs: any[]) => console.log(x))
  )
  .subscribe((val: any) => {
    this.resultObs = of(val);
    console.log(val);
    console.log(this.resultObs);
  });

This transforms the array held by data using map, by calling the filter method on the array to do the filtering.

Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense to me.  I am getting some wierd behavior that I'm not understanding why though.  After revising my code, after clicking complete, it removes the item the first time correctly....but if I try clicking complete on another item, it doesn't delete the item and insteads toggles the item to another item.

Maybe my implementation is the wrong way...I think I should be creating an observer on a data rather than having the data as an observable and trying to manipulate that
